# can't create .htaccess in Apache2

Tags: linux, .htaccess, apache2, debian

I've got a problem with Apache2 on my Linux Debian server. When I try to create .htaccess file, it does not appear. In apache2.conf I've got the .htaaccess configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of 2 possibilities - you do not have permissions to create the file or you are trying to view the file and unable to as it is hidden.

Use sudo or su to switch to root

`sudo nano .htaccess`

OR most likely

A file proceeded by a `.` (dot) in linux will not be seen unless you enable view hidden files in a file manager or run `ls -a` from a terminal

If using FTP the viewing will depend on your FTP client. For a GUI option such as filezilla will display hidden files automatically

Answer (score 2):

How do you create it? What if you `ls -a`? Maybe it's just hidden (as all files starting with dot)

Comment: Yes, you're right. But how can I set it to appear on FTP? Excuse me, I'm new in Linux.

Comment: It depends on your ftp client. What client are you using?

Comment: I'm using TotalCommander and PSPad editor but it works now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer seems to be solved, for starters, this depends on how the file is created. As said by @alleyoopster, if you do not have the permission to create the file, it would definitely show an error message like Permission denied or something so that you could understand the file was not created.

Now the next possibility would be that .htaccess file would be hidden. Any filename starting with a "." in front would be hidden. Actually, **.htaccess** is a file with an 8 letter file extension of **htaccess** just like abc.**mp4**. I have not used TotalCommander, but if you are using FileZilla, you have the ability to check/uncheck hidden files according to your wish. Instead if you are using terminal, you can type **ls -la** to view the files in that directory and their permission.  Hope this helps someone!!